# Jenkins' EnvInject Plugin does not persist values

Tags: variables, jenkins, plugins, environment

I have a build that uses EnvInject Plugin to set an environmental value.
A different job needs to scan last good Jenkins build of that job and get the value of that environmental variable.

This all works well, except sometimes the variable will disappear from build history. It seems that after some time passes, when I look at the 'Environment variables' section in build history, the injected value simply disappears.

How can I make this persist? Is this a bug, or part of the design?

If it make any difference, the value of the injected variable is +1500 chars and in the following format: 'component1=1.1.2;component2=1.1.3,component3=4.1.2,component4=1.1.1,component4=1.3.2,component4=1.1.4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like EnvInject and/or JobDSL have a bug.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set up a job that runs this JobDSL:

   `job('run_deploy_mock') {
      steps {
        environmentVariables {
          env('deployedArtifacts', 'component1=1.0.0.2')
        } 
      }
    }`
2. Run it and it will create a job called 'deploy_mock'
3. Run the 'deploy_mock' job. After build #1 is done, go to build details and check 'Environmental Variables' section for an entry called 'component1'
4. Run the JobDSL job again
5. Check 'Environmental Variables' section for 'deploy_mock' build #1. The 'component1' variable is now missing.

If I substitute the '=' for something else, it works as expected.

Created Jenkins [Jira](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-40112)